# how can I use array of threads to call the same function which updates on DB EF using linq?

Tags: c#, multithreading

when using array of threads to call the same function with different parameters "knowing that this function updates on DB records using linq and EF" I got an error at run time as:

> "Unhandled Exception: System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open."

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Thread[] threads = new Thread[4];
    int[] noOfTHreadSentences = new int[4];
    noOfTHreadSentences[0] = 350;
    noOfTHreadSentences[1] = 550;
    noOfTHreadSentences[2] = 678;
    noOfTHreadSentences[3] = 728;

    List<Sentence>[] sentences = new List<Sentence>[4];

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        int index = noOfTHreadSentences[i];
        if (i == 0)
        {

            sentences[i] = db.Sentences.Where(sent => (sent.FileId >= 1 &&
            sent.FileId <= index)).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            int indexPrev = noOfTHreadSentences[i - 1] + 1;
            sentences[i] = db.Sentences.Where(sent => sent.FileId >= 
                           indexPrev &&
                           sent.FileId <= index).ToList();
        }
    }    

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {

        int index = i;
        threads[i] = new Thread(new 
                     ParameterizedThreadStart(SetWordProperties));

        threads[i].Start(sentences[index]);

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        threads[i].Join();
    }
}


private static void SetWordProperties(object sentences)
{
    List<Sentence> sentencesList = (List<Sentence>)sentences;

    foreach (var sentence in sentencesList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(sentence.FileId);
        List<Word> wordsInSentence = new List<Word>();

        /* error is in this line */
        wordsInSentence = db.Words
                          .Where(w => w.SentenceId == sentence.SentenceId)
                          .ToList();



    }



}
```

Comment: Entity Framework DbContext is not thread safe. You can execute only one query at a time otherwise you will get an exception like you did above.

Comment: Why do you think you need threads here?

Comment: EF does only have one connection opened at a time. In a single connection you can only have 1 query at a time executing. They could be piped one after each other in a single transaction but still one execute at all time per connection. If you could get many connection open you could multithread and call multiple query. If they all update the same table chances are you will see little to no gain in performance.

Comment: Well, thank you for clarification, but now i need a way or source code to close and open connection using EF